# Using Find command with expr for to find four hours

Tags: shell, unix

I tried a lot to find the XML files in the particular folder(TO) which is holding for four hours. My system is HP UX so mmin is not supported and touch command i don't have permission. So i went to google search and finally created a Find command with my knowledge but the file count list shows wrong. What exact expr need to add in the below command to get the four hours old file.
 My folder(TO) contains one XML file but it shows 2
Please correct me whether the expr is correct if not what exact value I need to add in the find command.

```
find /data/abc/apactest/input/TO -name *.xml -mtime +`expr 2 * 10 / 5` -exec ls -ltr {} + | wc -l
```

it shows result 2 but I have one XML file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "holding for four hours" mean? That the file was created within the last four hours, accesses within the last four hours or modifier within last four hours? I would first find all files modified within last day and then filter using stat+date pipeline those within last 4 hours. Your command just `-mtime +4` finds files modified more then 4 days ago.

Comment: Hi The file was created within the last four hours